# Getting several contents of URL in PHP using CURL, Google CSE

Tags: php, json, curl, google-custom-search

I'm working on my project of using Google CSE. At this step I'm writing codes to retrieve JSON results from it.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
function cURL($url, $ref, $p) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
if ($p) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
}
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($result) {
    return $result;
} else {
    return '';
}
}

if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
} else {
echo 'salah bro!';
}
$cseNumber = 'aaa'; // Key for the API thing
$key = 'bbb'; //Key for Nofriani's account: sorta a password
$start = '1';
$file = cURL('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' . $key . '&cx=' . $cseNumber . '&q=' . $keyword . '&siteSearchFilter=i&alt=json&start=' . $start, 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' . $key . '&cx=' . $cseNumber . '&q=' . $keyword . '&siteSearchFilter=i&alt=json&start=' . $start, null);
echo $file;

?>
```

It worked perfectly and I got 10 first results of Google CSE. Unfortunately, the API restricts that only 10 results can be retrieved in bulk. Now, I intend to take 100 results in one results page (not in separated 10 page), by doing a looping. I added this:

```
$start= '';
$file = cURL('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' . $key . '&cx=' . $cseNumber . '&q=' . $keyword . '&siteSearchFilter=i&alt=json&start=' . $start, 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' . $key . '&cx=' . $cseNumber . '&q=' . $keyword . '&siteSearchFilter=i&alt=json&start=' . $start, null, $start);
return $file;

function getResult() {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 90; $i+=10) {
        $file .= cURL($url, $ref, $p, ($i + 1));
        for ($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
            echo $file;
        }
    }
}
```

?>

But it didn't work just like it did. I tried some tips here: [PHP How can I open several sources using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174152/php-how-can-i-open-several-sources-using-curl)
But it didn't work as well, :(
Can anyone please help me solve this? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot so many things like parameter and concatenation. Proper function will be like this

**Update**

```
function getResult($key,$cseNumber,$keyword) { // parameter added
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $file = cURL('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' . $key . '&cx=' . $cseNumber . '&q=' . $keyword . '&siteSearchFilter=i&alt=json&start=' . $i, 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' . $key . '&cx=' . $cseNumber . '&q=' . $keyword . '&siteSearchFilter=i&alt=json&start=' . $i, null); // . removed from here
        echo $file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I've added the parameters, but it still gave a blank page. :(

Comment: It gives fully blank page,. What do I do?

Comment: comment out the for loop and check weather it gives output for 10 results as you said or not

Comment: Yea it worked with 10 results, with $start='1' and echo $file. But if I use the for loop ($start ='' and return $file), I write the echo in the for loop, it didn't work, just a blank page.

Comment: function getResult($url, $ref, $p, $start) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 90; $i+=10) {
        $file = cURL($url, $ref, $p, ($i + 1));
        for ($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
            echo $file;
        }
    }
} ===> (sorry I don't know how to put a code in a comment)

Comment: I saw that the edited comment was just the same as mine.. Will you please add a new comment? I'm quite new member that I don't know how to see the edited function. Thanks..

Comment: @Nofriani Check the function below `Update` word.

Comment: I've done as you told me to. It finally worked. Oh God, thank you so much for your help!! ><

Comment: Ah.. Thanks, :) Sorry I can't vote up your answer, since my reputation isn't high enough. Thanks again.